# How to enable Express.post route once per day

Tags: express, datetime, routes

I have an express.js app that allows user to post an Act. I want to limit these posts to one per day. Beginning on the server side, I want to alter the route to post only if no Act was already posted by the current user on the same day. In the current route (shown below), I am attempting to compare current date at 00:00 am to the created_at date of the user's last Act s.t. that if created_at >= start_of_current_date, the post will not occur. However, created_at is recorded, but returns undefined in the conditional.

Here is my route:

```
// POST new Act route 
router.post('/', auth.required, async (req, res, next) => {
  const now = new Date();
  // return last created Act
  result = await Act
    .query()
    .where('users_id', req.user.id)
    .orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    .limit(1);

  console.log('this is the last act of user ', req.user.id, ': ', result);
  console.log('this is the created_at last act of user ', req.user.id, ': ', result.created_at);
  console.log('this is the start of today ', req.user.id, ': ', now.setHours(0,0,0,0));

  // conditional to disable if last Act.created_at == Today
  if(result.created_at >= now.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
    return Act.query()
    .insert({
      deed: req.body.act.deed,
      users_id: req.body.act.userId
    }) 
    .then( function () {
      res.json({ success: true, message: 'ok' });     // respond back to request
    })
  } else {
    res.json ({
      "message": "This user already acted today."
    });
  }
});
```

Here is the result in console including my console logs:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Running on localhost:8000
this is the last act of user  1 :  [ Act {
    id: 6,
    deed: 'Writing',
    users_id: 1,
    created_at: 2019-09-23T20:04:28.393Z,
    updated_at: 2019-09-23T20:04:28.393Z } ]
this is the created_at last act of user  1 :  undefined
this is the start of today  1 :  1569902400000
```

UPDATE: result is returning an array, so using result[0], I am able to get a value. h/e, need to convert the output to compare it to the current date. Here is the current output:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Running on localhost:8000
this is the last act of user  1 :  [ Act {
    id: 6,
    deed: 'Writing',
    users_id: 1,
    created_at: 2019-09-23T20:04:28.393Z,
    updated_at: 2019-09-23T20:04:28.393Z } ]
this is the date of the last act of user  1 :  2019-09-23T20:04:28.393Z
this is the start of today  1 :  1569902400000
```

Answer (score 0):

this works, using getTime() helper:

```
// POST new act route 
router.post('/', auth.required, async (req, res, next) => {
  const now = new Date();
  // return last created Act
  result = await Act
    .query()
    .where('users_id', req.user.id)
    .orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    .limit(1);

  console.log('this is the last act of user ', req.user.id, ': ', result);
  console.log('this is the date of the last act of user ', req.user.id, ': ', result[0].created_at.getTime());
  console.log('this is the start of today ', req.user.id, ': ', now.setHours(0,0,0,0));

  // conditional to disable if last Act.created_at == Today
  if(result[0].created_at.getTime() <= now.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
    return Act.query()
    .insert({
      deed: req.body.act.deed,
      users_id: req.body.act.userId
    }) 
    .then( function () {
      res.json({ success: true, message: 'ok' });     // respond back to request
    })
  } else {
    res.json ({
      "message": "This user already acted today."
    });
  }
});
```